# IntelliJ warns "Cannot resolve variable" on EL variables declared in parent page of include

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, el, facelets, uiinclude

I have created a table column which is defined in its own include file. This column is used by `<ui:include>` in a few other Facelets pages to be used in some datatables. The include column uses a variable called "linje" (which is a java class), which is defined in the parent page that includes the column.

Even though the code works, I cannot navigate to the java-class from the included file in IntelliJ. Is there some way to do this? I also get a lot of warnings from IntellJ "Cannot resolve variable "linje".

**Code that uses the column**

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{someMBean.someLinjeModel}"
                        reRender="ds-h" var="linje" id="vt"
                        rows="#{someBean.rows}" styleClass="standard"
                        rowClasses="odd,even">

            <ui:include src="someColumn.xhtml"></ui:include>
```

**Code from someColumn.xhtml**

```
<rich:column id="status" rendered="#{!linje.someRenderingCheck}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Status"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{linje.someText}"/>
</rich:column>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the variable `linje` as a parameter for the `<ui:unclude>`.

For example:

```
<ui:include src="someColumn.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="linje" value="#{linje}" />
</ui:include>
```

It will be a request parameter for `someColumn.xhtml` and you can *copy* it to another one (using the [`<c:set>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/set.html) tag), in order to avoid IDE warnings:

```
<c:set var="linje" value="#{linje}" />
```

Comment: If you use the `c:set` trick, then the IDE doesn't complain anymore that it doesn't know what `linje` is, but if you then try to use properties of `linje`, for example in an expression such as `#{linje.someText}`, it will complain that `linje` doesn't have a property `someText` (because it doesn't know what type `linje` has).